# How to handle web app (i.e. polymer starter kit) "focus" state on mobile browser

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, polymer-starter-kit

When browsing PSK on mobile browser, I notice some of the `<paper-*>` element, such as the `<paper-icon-button>` (i.e. menu icon) and the `<paper-fab>` are "stuck" on "focus" state when clicked. Is this an expected behavior? How should it be handled.

I understand that on desktop, you can "tab" to "navigate" to "focus" on element, but not sure if that's valid on a mobile browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I came across this issue ones. I noticed that each click on the paper-fab still works as expected. It is the just the color that is stuck in the focused state.
I know it is a ugly hack and maybe not suitable for your scenario, but I just set the same color of the button in it's active state.

```
--paper-fab-keyboard-focus-background
```

While going over the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-fab/elements/paper-fab), I realised that there is the focused property. It is a "readOnly" property but you could listen on that and change the background color when needed.

Comment: I am aware of overriding the `--paper-fab-keyboard-focus-background` CSS, which is a bit ugly. Wanted to know the proper way to handle `focus` state in general on touch only mobile device, which doesn't have a keyboard to navigate around different element.

Comment: If you come across any information regarding the "official" way please update it here as I am really interested how to handle it the right way.